# Personalizar FileUpload de Asp:Net con Boostrap 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap, fileupload

Hola comunidad tengo un problema con el control  FileUpload ya que requiero personalizarlo y he intentado con Bootstrap 4 pero no me queda como esperaba. ¿Alguien podría orientarme?.

Gracias.

Mi codigo Html

```html
 <div class="custom-file">                     
   <asp:FileUpload ID="SeleccionarArchivo" runat="server" 
     CssClass="custom-file-label" />   
 </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a que te refieres con personalizarlo

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate a aplicarle el estilo de Bootstrap 4 como se muestra en la imagen que publique. Pero Me sale con el botón de seleccionar Archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo agregas las referencias y los elementos.

```js
// nombre de archivo subido
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">seleccione archivo</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Te refieres a tener una salida como esta supongo